# How to get field that datagrid column is bound to?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

In my xaml I have modified each column header to include a button. For the command parameter I would like to use the column's data field name, instead of the header content. E.g. Instead of "Job Title" which is what the header content is, I want "JOB_TITLE".

For header content I would use:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenFilterCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding Content}">
```

How do I get the actual field name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i assume it right you want ***binding property name to which column is binded to pass as command parameter to OpenFilterCommand***.

Suppose columns are like this for your DataGrid:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NAME}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding JOB_TITLE}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

and want to pass property name `JOB_TITLE` as command parameter. This can be achieve like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenFilterCommand,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Column.Binding.Path.Path,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

> TemplatedParent (*DataGridColumnHeader*) --> Column (*DataGridTextColumn*)
>   --> Binding (*BindingBase*) --> Path (*PropertyPath*) --> Path (*Actual PropertyName*)

Comment: Also you seem to know your way around paths and noone has been able to give me an answer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976894/how-to-set-datatrigger-parameter-to-collection-sitting-in-parent

Comment: I have a very related issue to this one. Where {Binding Column.Binding.Path.Path is throwing error. This is occurring on a DataGridComboBoxColumn, the structure is different. Raised a new question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804196/how-to-bind-property-name-to-which-column-is-binded-to-pass-as-command-parameter