# How to bind property name to which column is binded to pass as command parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

On each DataGridColumnHeader I have a button that I use to open a popup. As a parameter it sends the column's bound Property name to the ICommand in my ViewModel.

This works well for any DataGridTextColumn however when it comes to a DataGridComboBoxColumn the structure is different.

How would I solve this?

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenFilterCommand, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Column.Binding.Path.Path, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Problem Column Definition

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Company" >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.CompanyCollection}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Company}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.CompanyCollection}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Company}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Which property name in this case you want to pass? `ItemsSource` name or `SelectedValue` name?

Comment: Company, so SelectedValue or what about either one of them.

Comment: I have added an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348895/632337) that how to get value for `DataGridTextColumn` where i suggested to use `Column.Binding.Path.Path` to get bound property name.

But that won't work in this case since `DataGridComboBoxColumn` does not have any binding property. If syntax is like the one you mentioned in question above, you can get like this:

For `SelectedValue` i.e. `Company`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenFilterCommand, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding 
                   Column.EditingElementStyle.Setters[1].Value.Path.Path, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

> TemplatedParent (*DataGridColumnHeader*) --> Column (*DataGridComboBoxColumn*) --> EditingElementStyle(*EditingElementStyle*) --> Setters(1) (*get first setter from style*) --> Value (*Setter Value*) --> Path (*PropertyPath*) --> Path (*Actual PropertyName*)

If you want to get `ItemsSource` property name, replace `Setters[1]` with `Setters[0]`.